# Detecting patterns in time-series data using R

Tags: r, time-series, clustering, pattern-recognition

I have a dataset of 258k observations with date time data for each observation in the format of `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. Each observation is a social media post made by a particular account.

Is there a way to detect or cluster observations by their timestamp similarity? The question I am trying to answer is: are there groups of accounts which post at or around the same time?

I am not quite sure how to approach this question. So far I have looked at time-series cluster analysis, but I am not sure if that is the right approach.

Comment: Generally clustering based on a time variable is possible, yes. However, you should consider what level of granularity you want to consider, as the results will be different if you cluster the activity based on time of day, day of week, month of year and so forth.

Comment: Thanks. I am aiming to cluster the activity by time of day.

Answer (score 0):

Extract features relevant for your task.

Just dumping the data into some black box won't work.

For example, make a histogram for the time of day.